# Is there such thing as a morphism of natural maps and what does it look like?

Tags: category-theory, morphism, 2-categories

I'm writing software to be general, so right now I'm writing a `NaturalMap` class which will be a graphical arrow that goes between any two `CategoryArrow`'s (functors are a subclass).

I was wondering how recursive I should make the thing while still finishing the project.

So what does a morphism of natural maps look like?  I am already very familiar with naturality squares for functors, but not beyond.

Comment: There are 3-categories/tricategories which have 3-cells. In particular, there is a tricategory of bicategories, [Bicat](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2Cat), whose 2-cells are pseudo natural transformations and 3-cells are modifications. Of course, we can keep going all the way to [$\infty$-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinity-category). That said, $\mathbf{Cat}$ is usually taken as a strict 2-category, so its higher structure, when viewed as a 3 or higher category, is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but a natural transformation $\eta: F \to G$ between functors $F,G: \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ can be seen as a functor $\eta: \mathcal C \times \mathbf 2 \to \mathcal D$ such that the following commutes:

[image]

where $\mathbf 2$ is the category with objects $0$ and $1$ and a unique non identity arrow $0\to 1$, and $i_0$ and $i_1$ are the inclusions of $\mathcal C$ as $\mathcal C\times\{0\}$ and $\mathcal C \times\{1\}$.

From there a straightforward generalization is that a morphism $\aleph: \eta \to \kappa$ between natural transformations is just a natural transformation between $\eta$ and $\kappa$ seen as functors, i.e. $\aleph$ is a functor $\mathcal C\times \mathbf 2\times\mathbf 2\to \mathcal D$ such that commutes:

[image]

In other words, $\aleph$ is the data of a commutative square

[image]

for every $X\in\mathcal C$, such that commutes the following cube for any $f: X \to Y$:

[image]

Comment: This describes a "free" morphism; normally the thing you want is a "based" morphism: that the restrictions to $C \times \{ 0 \} \times \mathbf{2}$ and $C \times \{ 1 \} \times \mathbf{2}$ are identity transformations... and since **Cat** is merely a 2-category you only have the trivial such thing. Put differently, as it pertains to the functor category $D^C$, you are describing a morphism of "arrows" rather than a morphism of "arrows from $F$ to $G$".

Comment: @Hurkyl Once again, I'm not sure what the OP is asking for. I was merely saying that seeing natural transformations as homotopies, one can then consider homotopies of homotopies and so on. (The assumption that the "based" version is the interesting one is not compelling to me: I'm pretty sure we can find interesting (pseudo) double categories whose horizontal bicategory has only identity 2-cells.)