# Natural transformations correspond bijectively to functors ... - but how?

Tags: category-theory

Lemma 1.5.1 in Emily Riehl's book 'Category Theory in Context' states:

Given a pair of functors $F,G \colon C \rightrightarrows D$, natural transformations corrspond bijectively to functors $H \colon C \times \mathbb{2} \rightarrow D$ so that the following commutes:

[image]

This is apparently obvious, but I keep going in circles around it. Naturality means that given $x \xrightarrow{f} y$, there are arrows $\alpha \in D$, so $\alpha_y \circ Ff = Gf \circ \alpha_x$, and the proof should construct $H$ from $\alpha$ and vice versa. I just can't get my thinking into the right shape.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854147/is-there-such-thing-as-a-morphism-of-natural-maps-and-what-does-it-look-like/2854290#2854290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\alpha:F\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}G$ denote a natural transformation.

Let $\iota:0\to 1$ denote the unique arrow $0\to 1$ in category $\mathbf2$.

---

Now define $H:\mathcal C\times \mathbf2\to\mathcal D$ by stating that $H(-,0)=F$, $H(-,1)=G$ on objects and arrows in $\mathcal C$. Further for every object $c$ of $\mathcal C$ let $H(c,\iota):=\alpha_c:F(c)\to G(c)$.

Then $H$  can be shown to be a bifunctor $\mathcal C\times \mathbf2\to\mathcal D$.

---

If conversely $H$ is a bifunctor $\mathcal C\times \mathbf2\to\mathcal D$ then it induces a natural transformation $\alpha:F\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}G$ defined by $\alpha_c:=H(c,\iota)$.

Comment: I’d just say the use of “bi”functor instead of “functor”, which is all these things are, could be confusing. One doesn’t talk about a bilinear map $A\otimes B\to C$, after all.

Comment: @KevinCarlson The term is used in e.g. CWM. Personally I don't think there is much chance on confusion (so will not change). If I am wrong after all then your comment is probably enough.

Comment: I don't really think the mention of a bi-functor is too confusing here. I had to look it up, but the real hardship in Riehl's book is the struggle to understand the enormous amount of examples from advanced maths that I have no experience with. Are most mathematicians really that well versed is such a wide variety of subjects? It's a scary thought.

Comment: "...most..." I don't think so! At least I am not one of them. Guys like Riehl might be exceptions on that (or have well informed assistents). Do not despair. A lot of what you do not understand can just be skipped. If you are surrounded by a lot of incomprehensible math, then also you can try to work from top to bottom. Persevere!

Comment: @drhab What on earth does it mean to apply H to (,)?  How can you apply a functor to both an object and an arrow at the same time?

Comment: @Owen It is a notational question. If $H:\mathcal C\times\mathcal D\to\mathcal E$ is a bifunctor then for every object $c$ in $\mathcal C$ we have the functor $H(c,-):\mathcal D\to\mathcal E$. It is prescribed on objects by $d\mapsto H(c,d)$ and on arrows by $f\mapsto H(1_c,f)$. Btw, nothing goes wrong if we see a functor merely as a function on arrows only, where we identify the objects with the corresponding identities. Objects can be looked at as special kind of arrows.

Comment: @drhab perfect! thank you!

Comment: Where does H send the pair $(k,\iota)$ if $k$ is not an identity?

Comment: @JohnMars If $k:u\to v$ in category $\mathcal C$ then:$$H(k,\iota)=G(k)\circ\alpha_u=\alpha_v\circ F(k):F(u)\to G(v)$$in category $\mathcal D$.